# the role of two nouns together

Tags: nouns, functions

When two nouns come together like *taxi driver*, the role of the first noun is noun adjunct.  Now the question is what is the second noun's role. I mean the role of *driver* in *taxi driver.*
Thanks

Comment: The role of *driver* is to be a noun for *taxi* to be an adjunct to. However, in general I would call *taxi driver* a compound noun and leave it at that.

Comment: user155384 The first noun is not an adjunct, it's a complement, just as "flower" is in *flower seller". The second noun is 'head' of the noun phrase. So in "taxi driver", "driver" is 'head' and "taxi" is complement.

Answer (score 1):

The syntactical name for *taxi* in "taxi driver" is *noun adjunct*.  Its role is modifier.  The syntactical name for *driver* in "taxi driver" is *head* of the noun phrase.  Its role (subject, object, etc) depends on its use in a sentence.

Comment: Hmmm, to be more technical, it's 'role' (syntactic function / grammatical relation) is, as you say, Head of the noun phrase. The function of the whole noun phrase itself is Subject/Object etc depending on its use.

Comment: @deadrat "Taxi" is surely obligatory here, so it must be a complement. Obligatory items are always complements, adjuncts are optional. It can't be a modifier as it's not describing "driver" as in "bad/irritable/dangerous driver" or "first-year" in "first-year student".

Comment: @BillJ Why is obligatory? "A: Call me a driver. B: What kind of driver? A: A taxi driver. B: OK, you're a taxi driver."

Comment: @deadrat  The noun 'taxi' does not denote a property of the driver. Think of it as 'a driver of taxis'.

Comment: @BillJ I don't agree.  It distinguishes him as a kind of driver, just like the prepositional phrase in "driver of a taxi."  Or don't you think the prepositional phrase modifies *driver*? That doesn't make *taxi* an adjective in the noun phrase, of course.

Comment: @deadrat It's possibly a fine distinction between modifier and complement, I admit, but the crucial point is that the driver is not some sort of taxi, i.e. 'taxi' does not describe the driver. In 'a driver of taxis', the PP 'of taxis' is a complement of 'driver', not a modifier, unlike the PP 'with a flat roof' in 'a house with a flat roof', which clearly is a modifier of 'house'. Where you do find nominals as pre-head modifiers is in examples like 'a first-year student', 'a brick wall', 'high octane petrol', and the like.

Comment: @BillJ Of course the driver is not some sort of taxi, just as in the phrase "tall driver," the driver is not some kind of tall.  Perhaps you're thinking of a "driver taxi" (which would be opposed to one of those automatic cars used as a taxi and not requiring a driver)  Note that *taxi* is not obligatory as complements are.  I can leave out the word *taxi* to say "A driver took me to the airport" without changing the meaning.

Comment: @deadrat You're perhaps missing the point. Modifiers ascribe some sort of property of the head noun. But "taxi" is NOT doing that as, say, the adjectival modifiers "tall//"dangerous"/Portuguese would. "Taxi" is obligatory here; it's required to complete the meaning of the head noun, and hence is a complement. Modifiers are optional; they merely provide additional non-essential information about the noun.

Comment: @BillJ I'm going to say that I see your point and leave the discussion.  This has nothing to do with you or your line of argument.  It's me.  I'm turning into That Internet Guy Who Has to Have the Last Word.  And I hate that guy.

Answer (score 1):

I would call taxi driver a compound noun with driver as main element and taxi as subelement giving additional information about the kind of driver.

I would not use the term adjective, which is a word class and no term for word formation. And I wouldn't use the vague term adjunct. It has several meanings.